# Error on set Header Media - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, header, media

I create a wordpress site on windows but when i try set the Header image i got this error

[image: Crop Image]

[image]

Someone have the same problem and the solution?

Comment: Go check your server error log.

Comment: @CBroe Dont have any logs on event viewer :s

Comment: Not talking about event viewer, talking about web server error log file.

Comment: @CBroe I think on windows web server log file was stored into event viewer. i'm wrong?

Comment: Depends on what server, and how you have it configured.

Comment: @CBroe My php error logs file was clean

Comment: _Server_ error log, not PHP.

Comment: I checked i dont have permissions on my uploaded files but i cant set the permissions too